# What is the difference between DEBUG on in Release Mode(while Optimize is on) and Debugging in Debug Mode?

Tags: c#, .net, release

I was unable to watch variables while debugging in release mode my C# project. However on enabling the DEBUG in the project settings, I was able to watch local variable values. I know symbol definitions are generated, but how would debugging and compile time and JIT optimization play together when debugging in release mode?

Answer (score 0):

Optimization is process what will change your code harmless. It is very hard to identify when your variable will be seen in release or not. Optimization can be performed, or not. For example, this code here:

```
int GetInt()
{
    var a = 1;
    var b = a;
    var c = b;
    return b;
}
```

Will probably dissapear in JIT, will be inlined or will be compiled to:

```
int GetInt() {return 1;}
```

As you see there is no variables you defined. In some cases it's possible to generate symbols for actual source, in some cases it is impossible, and you will never know until you decompile it and see IL.